# Bold matched text in a String in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I use the following code for replacing matched words within a String:

```
for ($i=0; $i < count($terms); $i++) {
    if ( $terms[$i] == '' || $terms[$i] == ' ' || strlen($terms[$i])==0 ) continue;
        $searchingFor     = "/" . $terms[$i] . "/i";
        $replacePattern   = "<strong>$0</strong>";
        $result['titulo'] = preg_replace($searchingFor, $replacePattern, $result['title']);
}
echo $result['title'];
```

Where 'terms' is an Array from $_GET['terms'].

All works fine except when user input strings containing characters like slashes. It arise an exception in preg_replace.

How can i solve this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: can you post an example of `$terms` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [preg_quote](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php):

```
$searchingFor     = "/" . preg_quote($terms[$i], "/") . "/i";
```

This function puts a backslash `\` before all characters used in preg syntax (`. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`) and also before all characters in the second argument, used here to escape your delimiter character `/`.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to consider using `str_ireplace` to do a case-insensitive replacement rather than regular expressions:

```
$terms = array('cat', 'hat');
$result['title'] = "the CAT in the hat";

foreach ($terms as $term) {
    if (trim($term) === '') continue;
    $result['title'] = str_ireplace($term, "<strong>$term</strong>", $result['title']);
}

echo $result['title'];
```

Output:

> the **cat** in the **hat**

One potential disadvantage of this is that the case of the original text is lost, taking on the case of the term in the replacement array. If that's a problem, you can adapt your original approach but use `preg_quote` to escape the characters in your input:

```
$terms = array('c\a/t', 'hat?');
$result['title'] = "the C\A/T in the hat?";

$terms = array_filter($terms, 'strlen'); // filter out empty values
$patterns = array_map(function($t) { return "/" . preg_quote($t, "/") . "/i"; }, $terms);

$result['title'] = preg_replace($patterns, "<strong>$0</strong>", $result['title']);

echo $result['title'];
```

Output:

> the **C\A/T** in the **hat?**